# Postgres/PostGIS skip intersect on features already intersected

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I have a collection of polygons(building outlines called "Build_poly") that I am intersecting with another table of flood defenses (also polygons called Flood_poly). 
When ever one of the building polygons intersect with a flood defense polygon I am updating the "defense" field of building polygon from 0 to 1.

What I have been trying to do to speed up my query is put in a condition where: if a building_poly has successfully intersected with a flood polygon for it to skip trying to intersect with any other flood defense polygons. This is what I've got so far, but I haven't managed to get any form of skip to work as this is my first trying to use postgresql.

```
UPDATE Build_poly
SET Defenses = 1
FROM Flood_poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(Build_poly.geom,Flood_poly.geom)"
```

Comment: Interesting... the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) mentions that _only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable_, but it doesn't specify if all matching rows are evaluated or if the planner limits the match to 1 row

Comment: one could update from a CTE, where a `LATERAL JOIN` limits the matches to 1 for each building. not sure if you can sqeeze time out of your `UPDATE` with *any* other construct, though...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about skipping unless you're talking about millions of intersections. It's probably a better idea to build up a [spatial index](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html) on your two tables and then run a normal query. I'd also set the defences column to a boolean (if you're only interested in True/False cases): CREATE INDEX build_poly_geo_index ON Build_poly USING GIST (geom); CREATE INDEX flood_poly_geo_index ON Flood_poly USING GIST (geom); ALTER TABLE build_poly ADD COLUMN defences boolean; UPDATE build_poly set defenses = ST_INTERSECTS(build_poly.geom, flood_p

Comment: I already have build a spatial index and we are talking about millions! There are approximately 6m buildings and 10k flood defenses.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question at all, in fact, it could be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Also, there will be multiple intersections, so setting defenses = ST_Intersects will probably give an error about multiple rows being returned by subquery, and, if not, will give an indeterminate answer and there are multiple potential intersections and non intersections.

Comment: Highly recommend against this design. It's not normalized, which will make keeping it correct error prone and a pain in the rear.

Comment: I ran this query on 10k points against about 50 pretty complex polygons. Took all of 300 ms. ST_Intesects won't give an error with multiple rows. It's a pretty simple and optimized check. If one shape/point meets the criteria then it will pass.

Comment: Orders of magnitude slower than what, John?

Comment: uh what happened here? ...didn't you write that as an answer @RedM? anyways, I run your suggestion on the same setup as in my answer, and it took about the same time as OPs query (about 3 times as long as with the `LATERAL JOIN`). it seems to work as you say, though.

Comment: I agree with @jpmc26 though, without an additional `ORDER BY` (in the case of my query) or, at least, the actual count of intersections, the *exact* results cannot be reproduced between runs; it is not predictable which row combo was responsible for the match. intuitively (and I'm sure there's written dogma out there) this is against some rule of DB analysis...

Comment: @ThingumaBob I guess strictly speaking, "denormalized" isn't the right term. Regardless, the "rule" is less of a rule and more of a practicality: generated data gets out of date when the original is modified. Storing it *in combination* with the data being edited is a structure ripe for bugs. Generated nightly in a separate table or something may be acceptable, if the consumers can deal with it being out of date. But regardless of whether that particular solution works, I would not store it on a table with volatile data.

Answer (score 4):

Following my comment I run a simple test on OSM data (*osm2pgsql* import; 1.7M polygons on 1M points; 340k updates);

Running (the equivalent to)

```
WITH
  lim AS (
    SELECT <id>
    FROM Build_poly AS bp
    JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Flood_poly AS fp
      WHERE ST_Intersects(fp.geom, bp.geom)
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS q
    ON true
  )

UPDATE Build_poly AS bp
  SET Defenses = 1
  FROM lim
  WHERE bp.<id> = lim.<id>
```

finished about 3 times faster.

Here, the `LATERAL JOIN` finds only one match per row in `Build_poly`, since you can use `LIMIT 1` in the inner query. The `UPDATE` will then be executed on comparing the `<id>` column (make sure that column of yours has an index in place).

---

**Update:**

You mentioned in the comments this approach is *5 times slower* than yours and I think, at this point, it's no matter of query design, it's the resource demand that's slowing down; an `UPDATE` in general is a resource heavy operation, and adding a `LATERAL JOIN`, with a sub-query execution for each row in memory, will enlarge the resource footprint quickly to a point where PG will need to work with inefficient intermediate/temporary files on disk (this might as well happen with your query, albeit not as extensive maybe). From my experience and following a suggestion I read years ago, creating a new table with the updates and dropping the old one instead usually is the better idea.

Some thoughts:

- leave it be, let it run overnight and put a trigger in place to update any new inserts on the spot
- create a new table with a foreign key each on the primary key of both your polygon tables and the `Defense` column only - it's a *relational* database after all...
- create a separate table with centroids (`ST_Centroid` or `ST_PointOnSurface`, depending on your polygons) of your `Flood-poly` table to run the intersection against
- try optimizing your PostgreSQL setup, e.g. `work_mem` etc. - this is where I usually head over to [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) (you could even migrate this question)

Comment: I've been trying to use this script but I keep getting the error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
LINE 13: UPDATE Build_poly AS bp

Comment: There is a missing ), to close out the WITH lim as ( statement. The answer is spot on, though.

Comment: @Yjelza uh oh...my bad, I corrected the closing bracket.

Comment: @JohnPowell and thx to point out! I see you got rid of that...very demanding other half of your name ,)

Comment: I believe your CTE is equivalent to `SELECT id FROM build_poly AS bp WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Flood_poly AS fp WHERE ST_Intersects(fp.geom, bp.geom))`. In which case, you could just drop the CTE and put the `EXISTS` check directly on the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause. Should speed things up even more.

Comment: +1 @jpmc26: that runs the same theoretical concept, *and would probably be the more specialized design*! I still can seem to get a speed benefit compared to the `LATERAL JOIN`, though; while the condition fulfills at the first match, the non-matching cases will still crawl the whole table...pretty much what the above structure does. anyways, I think it's worth an answer since the `EXISTS` design and purpose is pretty much the *direct* answer to OPs question

Comment: So I let your suggeston run overnight as I had to leave, it took 121m55s to run compared to my original query which ran in 23m47s

Comment: @Yjelza haha...damn. try with the `EXISTS` query mentioned above

Comment: @Yjelza just to be sure: do you have an index on the `<id>` column?

Comment: I do, I indexed it using CREATE INDEX id_idx on id USING btree (id)

Comment: @Yjelza How complex are your geometries? In number of vertices.

Comment: The Build_polys are circles but the Flood_poly's are complex polygons with multiple vertices, most if not all have 10 or more vertices

Answer (score 2):

Why not only test buildings that doesn't already have Defenses = 1

```
UPDATE Build_poly
SET Defenses = 1
FROM Flood_poly
WHERE Build_poly.Defenses != 1 and ST_Intersects(Build_poly.geom,Flood_poly.geom);
```

The planner will check the integer test first since that test has a lower cost than the intersects check.

Also be sure to have working indexed both on Build_poly.Defenses and on the geometry columns.

If your flood poly table is static you can also add a field that keeps information about if the test already is done. That way you will not have to recheck buildings outside flood_polygons again either.

```
alter table Build_poly add column already_checked int default 0;
     UPDATE Build_poly
    SET Defenses = 1
    FROM Flood_poly
    WHERE Build_poly.already_checked = 0 and ST_Intersects(Build_poly.geom,Flood_poly.geom);
```

A third way might be to add a trigger to the Build_poly table which only fires on the row that gets inserted or updated. Then put the test in a row level trigger and do the update from there.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I did try to run this, it took approximately the same time to run as my original query